# How do I integrate a unity android app into an existing app using android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, vuforia

I have a unity android application which I exported from unity, I wish to integrate it into my existing application using android studio. How would I go on to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, the first thing I did was export the unity project by **File->Build & Run->select android then switch platform->tick google android project->export** after that just import the project into Android Studio and it will handle the build, by then you can access the source code. Currently I'm still working on it to meet my specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

wow. Such a hard task, you can try opening up apk and implementing it in your project. But this is gonna be so painful and you might not get it to work if you are not experienced!!!